# jQuery UI position() not repositioning the element

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have a hyperlink which I am trying to reposition on the page using

```
$('#myLink').position({ my: "center", at: "center", of: "#contentArea", offset: "30 130" });
```

However it's not being placed in the new position. My page is a complicated html so I can't post it.
I tried different target elements but same results (both in IE8 & FF). I am using jQuery 1.4.2. There are no errors in the error console. $('#myLink').length = 1

Are there limitations for the position() function? How can the browser window or document be used as a target element?

Comment: You should edit the question to say that you’re using jQuery UI, not jQuery on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.position() is read only.  Use the .css() function to set positions.

Edit:

After looking further I see that you are referring to the following:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position

That being said, I think you may need to include the jQuery UI library in order for this to work.

Try including the following in the head of your page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I had the UI script reference in my code but the js file location was off.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/position/), .position() is a read-only method.